# Get names of classes as union type of string

Tags: typescript

I have several classes like

```
class A {}
class B {}
class N {}
```

Is it possible to generate a union type from the class names like

```
type Classes = "A" | "B" | "N"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a union type from the classes like this:

```typescript
type Classes = A | B | C;
```

Note there are no quotes. We're not dealing with string literals, we're dealing with type names.

No, you can't do it with string literals unless the classes are in an an object type where you can use the literals to refer to the interface's properties. For instance, this would work:

```typescript
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}
interface All {
    A: A,
    B: B,
    C: C,
}
type Classes = All[keyof All];
```

But that's round-about, if you already have access to the type names of the classes directly.

Note that `A`, `B`, etc. refer to the type of *instances* of the classes. I couldn't tell for sure whether you wanted that or the type of the class functions themselves. If the latter, you add `typeof` in front or `A`, `B`, and `C`:

```typescript
type Classes = typeof A | typeof B | typeof C;
```

or

```typescript
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}
interface All {
    A: typeof A,
    B: typeof B,
    C: typeof C,
}
type Classes = All[keyof All];
```

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Thanks. Yeah, it wasn't clear to me whether the OP wanted the instance type or the class type; I figured instance type, but really I should have done both in the first place.

Comment: No problem. I thought OP wants classes type, but you never know )